# How to add padding to SearchBar inside Horizontal StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms, searchbar, stacklayout

For some purpose I want to position `SearchBar` inside `StackLayout` whose `Orientation` is `Horizontal` and add padding to that `StackLayout` but I found that the `SearchBar` takes all the Width space as shown in second `SearchBar` while when the `Orientation` is `Vertical` it works normally as shown in first `SearchBar` the below image:

[image]

Here is the code for both `StackLayout`s:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="100,0,100,0">
        <SearchBar/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="100,0,100,0">
        <SearchBar/>
    </StackLayout>
```

I also tried to put the Horizontal-Orientated `StackLayout` into a Vertcal-Orientated `StackLayout` as shown in code below:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="100,0,100,0">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SearchBar/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

But it does not help too, So how to solve that problem?

Comment: Your question confuses me in a lot of ways can you just tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:** 
When you add a searchBar in `stackLayout` ,`stackLayout` will not make the subview fit the size. So though you set the `padding` .The searchBar will still Beyond the border of stackLayout.

**Solution:**

Put the srachBar in a `Grid`.

```
<StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"  Padding="100,0,100,0">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />                   
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

  </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```